# How to fadeIn and fadeOut paths once a class has been added or removed to them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding a class to some paths and I would like to fade theese one after the other once the class has been added to each. This is what I have tried

```js
$(".home button").on("click", function() {

  $("#hiButtons .btn-default").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var periodClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");
  var gapBetweenEach = 10;
  var speedOfFade = 150;
  
  $("svg path").each(function(i, path) {
    var cl = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).attr('class', cl.includes(periodClass) ? cl + ' fadeIn' : cl.replace(/fadeIn/g, '')).delay(gapBetweenEach * i).fadeIn(speedOfFade, function() {});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
       <path class="fadeIn"></path>
       <path class="fadeIn"></path>
       <path class="fadeIn"></path>
    </svg>
```

Comment: As a suggestion, I'd include a bit of HTML in your question so that your example is complete. Also, tell us why your code doesn't work - how does your result differ from the result you're trying to achieve? (Oh, and you're missing a `});`)

Comment: @Santi i have added the html  and it doesn't fade, if I knew why i wouldn't have asked a question, but thanks anyway

Comment: It was not showing up due to markup errors. I've edited your question to include a snippet, and added the two missing occurrences of `});`. Again, this doesn't solve your issue of a **Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example** because not only does your code not work, you haven't told us what's wrong with it. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for instruction, otherwise you run the risk of your question being closed.

Comment: fantastic, got down votes.

Comment: I told you what's wrong with your question, the downvotes should come as no surprise... From the link I posted above: *Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.* **and** *Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem.*

Comment: don't worry, i will solve it myself and paste the answer once it is done. Thanks

Comment: @Santi fixed it, placed the answer below. Thanks

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Had you just remedied your question, I would've given you [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wfgvxzmt/2/), which is a lightweight CSS version instead of depending on jQuery animations and nested functions.

Comment: @Santi thanks anyway, had of bit of rush to be honest but I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i resolved it, I first add the class and then I apply the delay to it, also changed the gap in between the fadings and the speed to better notice it.

```
$(".home button").on("click", function() {
  $("#hiButtons .btn-default").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var periodClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");
  var gapBetweenEach = 200;
  var speedOfFade = 400;
  $("svg path").each(function(i, path) {
    var cl = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).attr('class', cl.includes(periodClass) ? cl + ' fadeIn' : cl.replace(/fadeIn/g, ''))
    $(".fadeIn").delay(gapBetweenEach * i).fadeIn(speedOfFade);
  });
});
```